# React router two URL parameters &more

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I'm using react-router-dom and this is currently how it looks:

```
<Switch>
        <Route path={"/layouts/:layoutID"} component={Layouts} />
        <Route
          path={"/dashboard/:dashboardID"}
          component={Dashboards}
        />
</Switch>
```

When the user navigates to "/dashboard/:dashboardID" inside this component he can choose a sub-page onClick, and I want the URL structure will be "/dashboard/:dashboardID/:pageID" pageID will navigate to 'PageIdComponent' this component will get a 'match' props and will show pageID

Please see the attached file that shows the necessary structure.

What is the best way to implement it?[image]

Comment: If you are using state management like redux, you can update routes dynamically with the selected dashboardId.

Comment: You should put another router with a route child inside your `Dashboard` component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the child route inside your Dashboard component, then you can use the `match.path` value to build up a sub route:

```
<Route path={`${props.match.path}/:dashboardId`}>} component={SubDashboard} />
```

in order to make the path match what the parent's had and then add a new variable on top of that.

Then you can navigate to it using the `match.url` to make a link to the current URL and add the subPage to it:

```
<Link to={`${props.match.url}/pageFour`}>Page four</Link>
```

Instead of prop driling, React Router offers ways to get the relevant props to whatever components you desire via [`withRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC or various [hooks](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks). The hooks were introduced in version 5.1

To get the match via a hook you can use `const match = useRouteMatch()`

To get the relevant props via the HOC:

```
const Example = useRouteMatch(function Example({ match, location, history }) {
  return <div>{match.url}</div>;
});
```

For react router v6 (that's upcoming):

https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#nested-routes-and-layouts

Comment: What if the child is nested inside the Dashboard component but not a directly (two layers down) and I don't want to pass the 'match' prop all the way. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Shira, I added some information about the `withRouter` HOC and a relevant hook for getting the match information. These will allow you to use them from arbitrary locations in the project as long as they are within the Router Provider.